Can I apply for a Schengen visa to take my exams in my German university?
Can I apply for a Schengen visa to take my exams at my German university, as I don't think I will be able to get my study visa in time? Is that an acceptable reason to apply for a visa?
Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Which schengen visa, visitor? How'd you enroll to the university in the first place if you don't have a study visa? What passport(s) do you have?

Why do you mean with "write my exams"? (just some exams, or do you means also writing the final paper/dissertation/work) Or better: how long do it take?

Study is an option for purpose of journey on the short stay application form, IIRC. There’s also an ‘Other’ option and a subsequent question where you can provide more detail. Which would seem to indicate that you can apply for the purpose you mention in your question.

Yes, the visitor's visa. I am enrolled in online classes at the school. I want to write my end-of-semester exams. It will take a couple of weeks.
